# Two definitions for regular rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

A noetherian ring $R$ is said to be *regular* if every localization at a prime ideal is regular local.

On the other hand, there is another definition of regularity for non-noetherian rings:

> A (commutative) ring $R$ is said to be *regular* if every finitely
>   generated ideal has finite projective dimension.

In many books (e.g. 'Commutative Coherent Rings' by Sarah Glaz), it is said that these two definitions coincide for noetherian rings.

However, I can't prove it nor find any proof.

Is there any reference or proof? Thanks.

**Edit:**
By Serre's theorem, two definitions coincide for noetherian **local** rings and for noetherian rings **of finite dimension**.

Comment: Could you show how some ideal in  $k[t^2,t^3]$ fails to have a finite projective resolution ?

Comment: It has a cusp at the origin so it is not regular.

Comment: I see; I know that the "homological" regularity implies the "ideal-theoretic" regularity, and the converse is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have proven it!

Let $M$ be a f.g. $R$-mod, and take a projective resolution

$$\cdots \overset{d_2}{\to} P_2 \overset{d_1}{\to} P_1 \overset{d_0}{\to} P_0 \to M \to 0.$$

Put $K_i := \operatorname{Ker}d_i$. It suffices to show that there exists $N \geq 0$ such that $K_N$ is projective.

For each $p \in X:= \operatorname{Spec}R$, set $d(p):= \operatorname{pd}_{R_p} M_p < \infty.$

Then $(K_{d(p)})_p$ is free, and thus there is an open neighbourhood $U_p$ of $p$ in $X$ such that $K_{d(p)}$ is free on $U_p$.

Since $X$ is quasi-compact, we can choose a finite number of primes $p_1, \cdots p_n$ so that 
$$X = U_{p_i} \cup \cdots \cup U_{p_n}.$$

Set $N:= \underset{i}{\operatorname{max}} d(p_i )$.

For any $p\in X$, there is an $i$ such that $p \in U_{p_i}$.

Then $(K_{d(p_i)})_p$ is free and thus $d(p) \leq d(p_i) \leq N$.

Thus $(K_N)_p$ is free. Therefore $K_N$ is projective, as wanted.